# iOS Unanswered Question Issue?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

I've just jumped onto the iOS app on an iPhone 6 plus and have noticed that the unanswered questions had a count of 2 but both had accepted answers.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

[Here's a link to one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31520521/2075402)

Is this a bug as my understanding is this only questions without upvoted or accepted answered question should be in this view?

Comment: Did you look at about 16:16 UTC? [That's when the answer was accepted.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31520521/timeline) Then the answer is [yes](http://shouldiblamecaching.com).

Comment: @Deduplicator no it was 16:31 (BST) this evening